# accesing value data using request

Tags: java, servlets

I have form with two buttons having same name but different values ,how to get the value of both the buttons having same name but different value using request ?

```
<form action="controller">
    <input  class="smallbutton" name="op" value="login" type="submit"/>
    <input  class="smallbutton" name="op" value="SignUp" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

`request.getParameter("op")` gives only the value of login but not sign up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine why would you need such a thing. Two options, depending on what you are trying to acheive:

- use `request.getParameterValues("op")`
- use `<input type="hidden" value=".." />` and change the value using javascript according to your usecase.

Please clarify what's the bottom-line, i.e. what are you trying to do.

Comment: Generally, it is very useful if you can retrieve the value of the button to distinguish the button pressed when you have multiple buttons inside the same form.

Answer (score 0):

i think it depends whether you click on "SignUp" or on "login".

Since you cannot click on 2 buttons on 1 formular, you cannot get the 2 values

Answer (score 0):

> *request.getParameter("op") gives only the value of login but not sign up.*

This makes **perfect** sense. It returns the value of the *pressed* button. If you press `Sign up` then it will return `signup`. This way you know exactly what to do in the server side: login *or* signup. I really don't see any business reason why you would like to get the value for the both buttons regardless of the button pressed.